# functions folder in trace_stat folder of ftrace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debugging, profiling, ftrace

I  am learning ftrace, I read from the following link that I can enable function profiling using the 'function_profile_enabled' file.

```
mount -t tracefs nodev /sys/kernel/tracing
cd /sys/kernel/tracing
echo 1 > function_profile_enabled
echo "function" > current_tracer
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/trace/ftrace.html

The above link tells that the information is present in trace_stats/function (function0, function1..)

```
$ ls trace_stat/function*
trace_stat/function0   trace_stat/function15  trace_stat/function21  trace_stat/function28  trace_stat/function6
trace_stat/function1   trace_stat/function16  trace_stat/function22  trace_stat/function29  trace_stat/function7
trace_stat/function10  trace_stat/function17  trace_stat/function23  trace_stat/function3   trace_stat/function8
trace_stat/function11  trace_stat/function18  trace_stat/function24  trace_stat/function30  trace_stat/function9
trace_stat/function12  trace_stat/function19  trace_stat/function25  trace_stat/function31
trace_stat/function13  trace_stat/function2   trace_stat/function26  trace_stat/function4
trace_stat/function14  trace_stat/function20  trace_stat/function27  trace_stat/function5
root tracing
```

I only have 4 cores on my Ubuntu VM

```
$ grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo     
4
```

Can anyone explain me the actual significance of this file function<> in trace_stat folder
functions folder in trace_stat folder

Answer (score 1):

Those files are created by a loop over "for_each_possible_cpu()". For some reason, your kernel thinks your system has 32 possible CPUs enabled. There's been some issues with some bios that causes that.